# devops nuget unable to find microsoft.graph.auth preview

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, microsoft-graph-api

I am using microsoft graph client for azure ad b2c. It works fine locally, but it fails when deploying to azure devops with the following error: ##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1102: Unable to find package Microsoft.Graph.Auth with version (>= 1.0.0-preview.6)

I am using the pre-release version of the package.

Comment: How did you add the package reference to your project. What task you were using to restore the packages in the pipeline. I can install the package without issue with nuget install command in pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by updating the version of the Nuget to 5.0.0 in Devops pipeline nuget restore step.

Comment: That's great you fixed it. You can accept above answer of yours